# why this javascript containing html dom code does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

why the following piece of code does not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body>

      <h1 onclick="changeText(demo)">Click on this text!</h1>
      <h2 id="demo" >this text is to be changed</h2>
      <script>
      function changeText(id) {
       document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
     }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i have tried this in different browsers but
it is not working?

Comment: Please explain what you expect the code to do and how it's not working. But FWIW I think the problem is that you're passing a literal string to getElementById when you really mean to pass the parameter id? IOW remove the quotes in ("id").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you looked on your console, it would have told you exactly what is going on.

Always, always, always check the JavaScript console.

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

is looking for an id called `id`

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

EDIT:

Re-read your code, you want

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

Note that is NOT using quotes, so it will use the passed value.

Except, that doesn't work either.. because your syntax to call is off.  So you really want this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1 onclick="changeText('demo')">Click on this text!</h1>
  <h2 id="demo" >this text is to be changed</h2>
  <script>
  function changeText(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Ooops!";
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: upvote for the Always always always check the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it by `id` value, not the word id, in your example `id` value is `demo`, you need to change it into :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

Alternatively, you can write your HTML and JS code like this:

```js
var title = document.getElementById("clickMe");
title.addEventListener('click',function() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
 });
```

```html
<h1 id="clickMe">Click on this text!</h1>
<h2 id="demo">this text is to be changed</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the `id` to the function but you were using that as HTML control id. don't keep the id in the Quotation

```
function changeText(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Ooops!";
 }
```

If you want to know where you doing the mistake, another **debugging** approach is

1. Keep `debugger` in `changeText` function
2. Now open the DeveloperTool--> Source (In chrome)
3. Now Try to click on the `<h1>` tag